# flyway with docker fatal error: user root does not exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, gradle, flyway

I am trying to setup a spring boot application. I use flyway and postgres14. I ran my application using ./gradlew bootRun command. It worked fine and the migrations ran. But the user it took to create the tables were not the one I provided using spring.flyway.user. It used the system OS user.
This is where I am starting to get lost. What would have caused the issue?
Anyhow, I ran it like this because I was having trouble with docker and flyway. To be exact, my container kept failing due to the following error.[image]
Why does flyway keep looking for root user. I have mentioned my username as x, it created my tables using OS user and it is throwing error that root user is not found while running in docker environment?
Could anyone help me figure out what is happening here?